# How to format a number in Expression Language?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How can I make a formatted output for a number (e.g. `long` or `BigDecimal`) in EL? For example, I want to limit a number of decimal digits to 3 in

```
${result.returnValue.contract.balance}
```

Comment: in most cases you might end up adding both 'maxFractionDigits' and 'minFractionDigits, attributes to get it working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `<fmt:formatNumber/>`

http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html

For example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber 
     value="${result.returnValue.contract.balance}" 
     maxFractionDigits="3"/>
```

Comment: Upvote, and a quick comment - BigDecimal definitely works like this. If you are having problems, it's not the fault of BigDecimal :)

Answer (score 0):

The modern Java EE 5-8 approach with JSF is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
   <h:outputText value="#{result.returnValue.contract.balance}">
      <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="3"/>
   </h:outputText> ...
```

See also [Using the Standard Converters](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-page-core001.html#BNAST).
Since Java EE 6 (2009), JSF/Facelets is recommended.